# Oracle SQL reuse User Input

Tags: sql, oracle

I basically want to reuse an input to save the user from inputting same thing again..

Here's how the query looks like:

```
select * from table
where bb.bbn_from_dttm >= TO_DATE('&Bill_Date_ddmmyyyy','dd-mm-yyyy')
and bb.bbn_to_dttm <= LAST_DAY('&Bill_Date_ddmmyyyy');
```

I don't want the user inputting this twice and getting the value from the first input would give me the date range I need.

This is SQL Oracle.

Any clues?

Comment: use `'&&Bill_Date_ddmmyyyy'` at both the places in your code. -- `select * from table
where bb.bbn_from_dttm >= TO_DATE('&&Bill_Date_ddmmyyyy','dd-mm-yyyy')
and bb.bbn_to_dttm <= LAST_DAY('&&Bill_Date_ddmmyyyy');`

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 Wouldn't this fail the second time you run the query as it would not ask for input? Also if so Could you change the original query to how you suggest it - would be helpful.

Comment: In a single session, it will not ask for the input again. If you run it in another session then only it will ask you for input again.

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 Got it :) Thanks!

Comment: In case, If you want to undefine the value in the same session then you can execute the following command before executing your query:
`UNDEFINE Bill_Date_ddmmyyyy` then execute your query `select * from table where bb.bbn_from_dttm >= TO_DATE('&&Bill_Date_ddmmyyyy','dd-mm-yyyy') and bb.bbn_to_dttm <= LAST_DAY('&&Bill_Date_ddmmyyyy');` -- It will ask for user input, once after UNDEFINE is executed but It will not ask for input for multiple usage of same substitution variable in session untill it is again UNDEFINED.

Comment: Making WHERE condition as `bb.bbn_to_dttm between date'&&Bill_Date_yyyy_mm_dd' and date'&&Bill_Date_yyyy_mm_dd'` without less, greater and equal signs, and entering the value as `2019-07-04`(conforming to ISO standard) is enough
 whenever prompted.

Answer (score 1):

Note the use of an inline view to convert the input string into a date (just once for the entire query) - then the rest of the query uses the date created in this inline view, not the user's input. Change `&` to `&&` if you need the query to use the same input whenever run in the same session (although in most cases that's not what users would want).

```
select bb.* 
from   my_table bb
       join
       ( select TO_DATE('&Bill_Date_ddmmyyyy','dd-mm-yyyy') as bill_date
         from   dual
       ) d
  on   bb.bbn_from_dttm >= d.bill_date and bb.bbn_to_dttm <= LAST_DAY(d.bill_date);
```